# Parsing XML with headers

Tags: python, xml, parsing, urllib2, sitemap

I am parsing some sitemap's xml and I have stumbled across one site in particular that implements cloudflare ddos protection. I originally had something like this:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib, urllib2

url='http://rsvpgallery.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=1&to=9999999999'
xml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

Checking the xml variable, we can see that it results in the cloudflare protection page and that the site has banned my access based on my browser's signature.

To remedy this I want to implement the addition of a User-Agent header. 
I'm thinking of something like this:

```
...
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/47.0.2526.106 Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36')
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
url = resp.read()
...
```

But when I go to declare xml with this new url variable I get this error:

```
 xml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return self.open_unknown(fullurl, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 217, in open_unknown
    raise IOError, ('url error', 'unknown url type', type)
IOError: [Errno url error] unknown url type: '?xml%20version=%221.0%22%20encoding=%22utf-8%22?%3e%0a%3curlset%20xmlns=%22http'
```

Any thoughts or ideas on how to go about fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be work for you:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib2 as net

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0',
}

url='http://rsvpgallery.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=1&to=9999999999'
req = net.Request(url, headers=headers)
xml = net.urlopen(req).read()

print xml
```

Your script should be working anyway... It seems you've swapped the url var by xml var, it's just a little confusion.

Comment: Quick and efficient response! Thank you!